# Reason for Solace CLIENT_CLIENT_DISCONNECT

Tags: kubernetes, amqp, solace

Recently some of the microservice AMQP applications are disconnected based on the solace event logs. However, the microservice AMQP applications did not detect any "CONNECTION_CLOSE" event. And, the applications did not trigger DISCONNECT action.

Is there any documentation of the reasons and the explanation for the causes of them? How to troubleshoot to find more information?

- K8s : Using Microk8s (3 Nodes)
- Microservices Application : Using NodeJS (AMQP-PROMISE)
- Solace : Using Docker-Compose (Version 9.12.1.17) - Outside the K8s Cluster

```
2022-05-21T01:00:10.139+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_UNBIND: default #amqp/client/cc91953864d36d09/food-input-adaptor/d874f7c9-9620-2243-b12f-3fe039a4f1eb Client (59) #amqp/client/cc91953864d36d09/food-in
put-adaptor/d874f7c9-9620-2243-b12f-3fe039a4f1eb username testAccount Unbind to Flow Id (78), ForwardingMode(StoreAndForward), final statistics - flow(255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2997, 0), isActive(No), Reason(Client disconnected)
2022-05-21T01:00:10.141+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_DISCONNECT: default #amqp/client/cc91953864d36d09/food-input-adaptor/d874f7c9-9620-2243-b12f-3fe039a4f1eb Client (59) #amqp/client/cc91953864d36d09/food-
input-adaptor/d874f7c9-9620-2243-b12f-3fe039a4f1eb username testAccount WebSessionId (N/A) reason(Peer TCP Reset) final statistics - dp(104, 2955, 2951, 2997, 3055, 5952, 6915, 118733, 3991887, 1496290, 3998802, 1615023, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0) conn(0, 0, 192.168.105.161:60776, CLOSD, 0, 0, 0) zip(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00, 0.00, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) web(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SslVersion(), SslCipher()
2022-05-21T01:00:10.613+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_DISCONNECT: default #amqp/client/26253499ce1fbce5/a2c7ad9b-540d-4116-85cf-e8dfe8d43d71 Client (4) #amqp/client/26253499ce1fbce5/a2c7ad9b-540d-4116-85cf
-e8dfe8d43d71 username testAccount WebSessionId (N/A) reason(Peer TCP Reset) final statistics - dp(2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 223, 401, 0, 0, 223, 401, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) conn(0, 0, 192.168.105.161:38101, CLOSD, 0, 0, 0) zip(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.
00, 0.00, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) web(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SslVersion(), SslCipher()
2022-05-21T01:00:13.141+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_CLOSE_FLOW: default #amqp/client/cc91953864d36d09/food-input-adaptor/d874f7c9-9620-2243-b12f-3fe039a4f1eb Client (59) #amqp/client/cc91953864d36d09/food-
input-adaptor/d874f7c9-9620-2243-b12f-3fe039a4f1eb username testAccount Pub flow session flow name 8b608e84651042bbaa485cdea5fd00ef (7), transacted session id -1, publisher id 6, last message id 4573, window size 247, final statistics - flow
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2951)
2022-05-21T01:01:10.158+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: VPN: VPN_AD_QENDPT_DELETE: default - Message VPN (0) Topic Endpoint food-input-adaptor/d874f7c9-9620-2243-b12f-3fe039a4f1eb/food-input-adaptor deleted, final statistics - sp
ool(145051, 145023, 145051, 0, 0, 0, 1202584, 2997) bind(1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
2022-05-21T01:31:46.979+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: SYSTEM: SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATION_SESSION_OPENED: - - SEMP session 192.168.7.1-48 internal authentication opened for user localAccount (admin)
2022-05-21T01:35:13.360+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: SYSTEM: SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATION_SESSION_OPENED: - - CLI session pts/0 [10572] internal authentication opened for user appuser (appuser)
```

After a while

```
2022-05-21T01:51:36.127+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: VPN: VPN_AD_QENDPT_CREATE: default - Message VPN (0) Topic Endpoint food-input-adaptor/703ee98b-f552-a94f-bb00-7b59cf576ae4/food-input-adaptor created
2022-05-21T01:51:36.130+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_BIND_SUCCESS: default #amqp/client/4b2080ad03c99e16/food-input-adaptor/703ee98b-f552-a94f-bb00-7b59cf576ae4 Client (87) #amqp/client/4b2080ad03c99e16/
food-input-adaptor/703ee98b-f552-a94f-bb00-7b59cf576ae4 username testAccount Bind to Non-Durable Topic Endpoint food-input-adaptor/703ee98b-f552-a94f-bb00-7b59cf576ae4/food-input-adaptor Topic(caas/food/input), AccessType(Exclusive), Quota(5000M
B), MaxMessageSize(10000000B), AllOthersPermission(No-Access), RespectTTL(No), RejectMsgToSenderOnDiscard(No), ReplayFrom(N/A), GrantedPermission(Read|Consume|Modify-Topic|Delete), FlowType(Consumer-Redelivery), FlowId(85), ForwardingMod
e(StoreAndForward), MaxRedelivery(0), TransactedSessionId(-1) completed
2022-05-21T01:51:39.692+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_UNBIND: default #amqp/client/4b2080ad03c99e16/food-input-adaptor/703ee98b-f552-a94f-bb00-7b59cf576ae4 Client (87) #amqp/client/4b2080ad03c99e16/food-in
put-adaptor/703ee98b-f552-a94f-bb00-7b59cf576ae4 username testAccount Unbind to Flow Id (85), ForwardingMode(StoreAndForward), final statistics - flow(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), isActive(No), Reason(Client disconnected)
2022-05-21T01:51:39.693+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_DISCONNECT: default #amqp/client/4b2080ad03c99e16/food-input-adaptor/703ee98b-f552-a94f-bb00-7b59cf576ae4 Client (87) #amqp/client/4b2080ad03c99e16/food-
input-adaptor/703ee98b-f552-a94f-bb00-7b59cf576ae4 username testAccount WebSessionId (N/A) reason(Peer TCP Reset) final statistics - dp(5, 4, 0, 0, 5, 4, 417, 693, 0, 0, 417, 693, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) conn(0, 0, 192.168.7.1:63510, C
LOSD, 0, 0, 0) zip(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00, 0.00, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) web(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SslVersion(), SslCipher()
2022-05-21T01:51:42.693+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_CLOSE_FLOW: default #amqp/client/4b2080ad03c99e16/food-input-adaptor/703ee98b-f552-a94f-bb00-7b59cf576ae4 Client (87) #amqp/client/4b2080ad03c99e16/food-
input-adaptor/703ee98b-f552-a94f-bb00-7b59cf576ae4 username testAccount Pub flow session flow name 9ad69d02d736443489115e34529e6e68 (22), transacted session id -1, publisher id 21, last message id 1544, window size 247, final statistics - fl
ow(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
2022-05-21T01:51:42.818+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: SYSTEM: SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATION_SESSION_CLOSED: - - CLI session pts/0 [10572] closed for user appuser (appuser)
2022-05-21T01:52:39.712+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: VPN: VPN_AD_QENDPT_DELETE: default - Message VPN (0) Topic Endpoint food-input-adaptor/703ee98b-f552-a94f-bb00-7b59cf576ae4/food-input-adaptor deleted, final statistics - sp
ool(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) bind(1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
2022-05-21T01:53:54.892+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_CONNECT: default #amqp/client/eb13bf695e4cdc3a Client (86) #amqp/client/eb13bf695e4cdc3a username testAccount OriginalClientUsername(testAccount) WebSessionId
(N/A) connected to 172.22.0.2:5672 from 192.168.7.1:63572 version(Unknown) platform(Unknown) SslVersion() SslCipher() APIuser(Unknown) authScheme(Basic) authorizationGroup() clientProfile(default) ACLProfile(default) SSLDowngradedToPlain
Text(No) SSLNegotiatedTo() SslRevocation(Not Checked) Capabilities() SslValidityNotAfter(-)
2022-05-21T01:53:54.919+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_NAME_CHANGE: default #amqp/client/eb13bf695e4cdc3a/food-input-adaptor/c296075d-66ae-5843-9a49-118437114e88 Client (86) #amqp/client/eb13bf695e4cdc3a/f
pl-input-adaptor/c296075d-66ae-5843-9a49-118437114e88 username testAccount changed name from #amqp/client/eb13bf695e4cdc3a
2022-05-21T01:53:54.964+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_OPEN_FLOW: default #amqp/client/eb13bf695e4cdc3a/food-input-adaptor/c296075d-66ae-5843-9a49-118437114e88 Client (86) #amqp/client/eb13bf695e4cdc3a/food-i
nput-adaptor/c296075d-66ae-5843-9a49-118437114e88 username testAccount Pub flow session flow name f18e140a02a9453ab6eb03425ee7d3f9 (23), transacted session id -1, publisher id 22, last message id 1291, window size 247
2022-05-21T01:53:54.979+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: VPN: VPN_AD_QENDPT_CREATE: default - Message VPN (0) Topic Endpoint food-input-adaptor/c296075d-66ae-5843-9a49-118437114e88/food-input-adaptor created
2022-05-21T01:53:54.983+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_BIND_SUCCESS: default #amqp/client/eb13bf695e4cdc3a/food-input-adaptor/c296075d-66ae-5843-9a49-118437114e88 Client (86) #amqp/client/eb13bf695e4cdc3a/
food-input-adaptor/c296075d-66ae-5843-9a49-118437114e88 username testAccount Bind to Non-Durable Topic Endpoint food-input-adaptor/c296075d-66ae-5843-9a49-118437114e88/food-input-adaptor Topic(caas/food/input), AccessType(Exclusive), Quota(5000M
B), MaxMessageSize(10000000B), AllOthersPermission(No-Access), RespectTTL(No), RejectMsgToSenderOnDiscard(No), ReplayFrom(N/A), GrantedPermission(Read|Consume|Modify-Topic|Delete), FlowType(Consumer-Redelivery), FlowId(86), ForwardingMod
e(StoreAndForward), MaxRedelivery(0), TransactedSessionId(-1) completed
2022-05-21T01:53:56.502+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_UNBIND: default #amqp/client/eb13bf695e4cdc3a/food-input-adaptor/c296075d-66ae-5843-9a49-118437114e88 Client (86) #amqp/client/eb13bf695e4cdc3a/food-in
put-adaptor/c296075d-66ae-5843-9a49-118437114e88 username testAccount Unbind to Flow Id (86), ForwardingMode(StoreAndForward), final statistics - flow(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), isActive(No), Reason(Client disconnected)
2022-05-21T01:53:56.503+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_DISCONNECT: default #amqp/client/eb13bf695e4cdc3a/food-input-adaptor/c296075d-66ae-5843-9a49-118437114e88 Client (86) #amqp/client/eb13bf695e4cdc3a/food-
input-adaptor/c296075d-66ae-5843-9a49-118437114e88 username testAccount WebSessionId (N/A) reason(Peer TCP Reset) final statistics - dp(5, 4, 0, 0, 5, 4, 417, 693, 0, 0, 417, 693, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) conn(0, 0, 192.168.7.1:63572, C
LOSD, 0, 0, 0) zip(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00, 0.00, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) web(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SslVersion(), SslCipher()
2022-05-21T01:53:59.503+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_CLOSE_FLOW: default #amqp/client/eb13bf695e4cdc3a/food-input-adaptor/c296075d-66ae-5843-9a49-118437114e88 Client (86) #amqp/client/eb13bf695e4cdc3a/food-
input-adaptor/c296075d-66ae-5843-9a49-118437114e88 username testAccount Pub flow session flow name f18e140a02a9453ab6eb03425ee7d3f9 (23), transacted session id -1, publisher id 22, last message id 1291, window size 247, final statistics - fl
ow(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
2022-05-21T01:54:56.521+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: VPN: VPN_AD_QENDPT_DELETE: default - Message VPN (0) Topic Endpoint food-input-adaptor/c296075d-66ae-5843-9a49-118437114e88/food-input-adaptor deleted, final statistics - sp
ool(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) bind(1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
2022-05-21T01:55:15.625+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_CONNECT: default #amqp/client/5d9a55a247c9c1bf Client (68) #amqp/client/5d9a55a247c9c1bf username testAccount OriginalClientUsername(testAccount) WebSessionId
(N/A) connected to 172.22.0.2:5672 from 192.168.7.1:63584 version(Unknown) platform(Unknown) SslVersion() SslCipher() APIuser(Unknown) authScheme(Basic) authorizationGroup() clientProfile(default) ACLProfile(default) SSLDowngradedToPlain
Text(No) SSLNegotiatedTo() SslRevocation(Not Checked) Capabilities() SslValidityNotAfter(-)
2022-05-21T01:55:15.649+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_NAME_CHANGE: default #amqp/client/5d9a55a247c9c1bf/food-input-adaptor/44920b4d-7a3e-f844-96e3-e67cebc3ac80 Client (68) #amqp/client/5d9a55a247c9c1bf/f
pl-input-adaptor/44920b4d-7a3e-f844-96e3-e67cebc3ac80 username testAccount changed name from #amqp/client/5d9a55a247c9c1bf
2022-05-21T01:55:15.696+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_OPEN_FLOW: default #amqp/client/5d9a55a247c9c1bf/food-input-adaptor/44920b4d-7a3e-f844-96e3-e67cebc3ac80 Client (68) #amqp/client/5d9a55a247c9c1bf/food-i
nput-adaptor/44920b4d-7a3e-f844-96e3-e67cebc3ac80 username testAccount Pub flow session flow name e216e8c8310d499083f1684609ef573f (24), transacted session id -1, publisher id 23, last message id 1542, window size 247
2022-05-21T01:55:15.711+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: VPN: VPN_AD_QENDPT_CREATE: default - Message VPN (0) Topic Endpoint food-input-adaptor/44920b4d-7a3e-f844-96e3-e67cebc3ac80/food-input-adaptor created
2022-05-21T01:55:15.713+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_BIND_SUCCESS: default #amqp/client/5d9a55a247c9c1bf/food-input-adaptor/44920b4d-7a3e-f844-96e3-e67cebc3ac80 Client (68) #amqp/client/5d9a55a247c9c1bf/
food-input-adaptor/44920b4d-7a3e-f844-96e3-e67cebc3ac80 username testAccount Bind to Non-Durable Topic Endpoint food-input-adaptor/44920b4d-7a3e-f844-96e3-e67cebc3ac80/food-input-adaptor Topic(caas/food/input), AccessType(Exclusive), Quota(5000M
B), MaxMessageSize(10000000B), AllOthersPermission(No-Access), RespectTTL(No), RejectMsgToSenderOnDiscard(No), ReplayFrom(N/A), GrantedPermission(Read|Consume|Modify-Topic|Delete), FlowType(Consumer-Redelivery), FlowId(87), ForwardingMod
e(StoreAndForward), MaxRedelivery(0), TransactedSessionId(-1) completed
2022-05-21T01:55:16.569+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_UNBIND: default #amqp/client/5d9a55a247c9c1bf/food-input-adaptor/44920b4d-7a3e-f844-96e3-e67cebc3ac80 Client (68) #amqp/client/5d9a55a247c9c1bf/food-in
put-adaptor/44920b4d-7a3e-f844-96e3-e67cebc3ac80 username testAccount Unbind to Flow Id (87), ForwardingMode(StoreAndForward), final statistics - flow(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), isActive(No), Reason(Client disconnected)
2022-05-21T01:55:16.570+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_DISCONNECT: default #amqp/client/5d9a55a247c9c1bf/food-input-adaptor/44920b4d-7a3e-f844-96e3-e67cebc3ac80 Client (68) #amqp/client/5d9a55a247c9c1bf/food-
---Press any key to continue, or `q' to quit---
input-adaptor/44920b4d-7a3e-f844-96e3-e67cebc3ac80 username testAccount WebSessionId (N/A) reason(Peer TCP Reset) final statistics - dp(5, 4, 0, 0, 5, 4, 417, 693, 0, 0, 417, 693, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) conn(0, 0, 192.168.7.1:63584, C
LOSD, 0, 0, 0) zip(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00, 0.00, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) web(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SslVersion(), SslCipher()
2022-05-21T01:55:19.570+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_CLOSE_FLOW: default #amqp/client/5d9a55a247c9c1bf/food-input-adaptor/44920b4d-7a3e-f844-96e3-e67cebc3ac80 Client (68) #amqp/client/5d9a55a247c9c1bf/food-
input-adaptor/44920b4d-7a3e-f844-96e3-e67cebc3ac80 username testAccount Pub flow session flow name e216e8c8310d499083f1684609ef573f (24), transacted session id -1, publisher id 23, last message id 1542, window size 247, final statistics - fl
ow(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
2022-05-21T01:56:16.589+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: VPN: VPN_AD_QENDPT_DELETE: default - Message VPN (0) Topic Endpoint food-input-adaptor/44920b4d-7a3e-f844-96e3-e67cebc3ac80/food-input-adaptor deleted, final statistics - sp
ool(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) bind(1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
2022-05-21T01:56:27.372+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_CONNECT: default #amqp/client/b45f6c87b0e76616 Client (67) #amqp/client/b45f6c87b0e76616 username testAccount OriginalClientUsername(testAccount) WebSessionId
(N/A) connected to 172.22.0.2:5672 from 192.168.7.1:63599 version(Unknown) platform(Unknown) SslVersion() SslCipher() APIuser(Unknown) authScheme(Basic) authorizationGroup() clientProfile(default) ACLProfile(default) SSLDowngradedToPlain
Text(No) SSLNegotiatedTo() SslRevocation(Not Checked) Capabilities() SslValidityNotAfter(-)
2022-05-21T01:56:27.397+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_NAME_CHANGE: default #amqp/client/b45f6c87b0e76616/food-input-adaptor/bc685049-76db-7345-9945-8cc07b6035ae Client (67) #amqp/client/b45f6c87b0e76616/f
pl-input-adaptor/bc685049-76db-7345-9945-8cc07b6035ae username testAccount changed name from #amqp/client/b45f6c87b0e76616
2022-05-21T01:56:27.441+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_OPEN_FLOW: default #amqp/client/b45f6c87b0e76616/food-input-adaptor/bc685049-76db-7345-9945-8cc07b6035ae Client (67) #amqp/client/b45f6c87b0e76616/food-i
nput-adaptor/bc685049-76db-7345-9945-8cc07b6035ae username testAccount Pub flow session flow name 04c9bfb86bac4f3dba9dba89b4724cde (25), transacted session id -1, publisher id 24, last message id 1290, window size 247
2022-05-21T01:56:27.454+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: VPN: VPN_AD_QENDPT_CREATE: default - Message VPN (0) Topic Endpoint food-input-adaptor/bc685049-76db-7345-9945-8cc07b6035ae/food-input-adaptor created
2022-05-21T01:56:27.456+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_BIND_SUCCESS: default #amqp/client/b45f6c87b0e76616/food-input-adaptor/bc685049-76db-7345-9945-8cc07b6035ae Client (67) #amqp/client/b45f6c87b0e76616/
food-input-adaptor/bc685049-76db-7345-9945-8cc07b6035ae username testAccount Bind to Non-Durable Topic Endpoint food-input-adaptor/bc685049-76db-7345-9945-8cc07b6035ae/food-input-adaptor Topic(caas/food/input), AccessType(Exclusive), Quota(5000M
B), MaxMessageSize(10000000B), AllOthersPermission(No-Access), RespectTTL(No), RejectMsgToSenderOnDiscard(No), ReplayFrom(N/A), GrantedPermission(Read|Consume|Modify-Topic|Delete), FlowType(Consumer-Redelivery), FlowId(88), ForwardingMod
e(StoreAndForward), MaxRedelivery(0), TransactedSessionId(-1) completed
2022-05-21T01:56:32.434+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_UNBIND: default #amqp/client/b45f6c87b0e76616/food-input-adaptor/bc685049-76db-7345-9945-8cc07b6035ae Client (67) #amqp/client/b45f6c87b0e76616/food-in
put-adaptor/bc685049-76db-7345-9945-8cc07b6035ae username testAccount Unbind to Flow Id (88), ForwardingMode(StoreAndForward), final statistics - flow(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), isActive(No), Reason(Client disconnected)
2022-05-21T01:56:32.435+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_DISCONNECT: default #amqp/client/b45f6c87b0e76616/food-input-adaptor/bc685049-76db-7345-9945-8cc07b6035ae Client (67) #amqp/client/b45f6c87b0e76616/food-
input-adaptor/bc685049-76db-7345-9945-8cc07b6035ae username testAccount WebSessionId (N/A) reason(Client Disconnect Received) final statistics - dp(7, 4, 0, 0, 7, 4, 493, 693, 0, 0, 493, 693, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) conn(0, 0, 192.168.
8.1:63599, ESTAB, 0, 0, 0) zip(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00, 0.00, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) web(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SslVersion(), SslCipher()
2022-05-21T01:56:35.436+00:00 <local3.info> 031cdc6fee4f event: CLIENT: CLIENT_CLIENT_CLOSE_FLOW: default #amqp/client/b45f6c87b0e76616/food-input-adaptor/bc685049-76db-7345-9945-8cc07b6035ae Client (67) #amqp/client/b45f6c87b0e76616/food-
input-adaptor/bc685049-76db-7345-9945-8cc07b6035ae username testAccount Pub flow session flow name 04c9bfb86bac4f3dba9dba89b4724cde (25), transacted session id -1, publisher id 24, last message id 1290, window size 247, final statistics - fl
ow(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
2022-05-21T01:57:32.453+00:00 <local3.notice> 031cdc6fee4f event: VPN: VPN_AD_QENDPT_DELETE: default - Message VPN (0) Topic Endpoint food-input-adaptor/bc685049-76db-7345-9945-8cc07b6035ae/food-input-adaptor deleted, final statistics - sp
ool(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) bind(1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the discussion on this in the Solace Developer Community at https://solace.community/discussion/1342/reason-for-solace-client-client-disconnect

Comment: Yeah. I found out it is the k8s node sent [RST] packet to the solace message broker.